# NSSet and NSCountedSet, when is the best time to use them?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, foundation

These two collection types are rarely used by me as I'm typically using their counter parts, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and the equivalent mutables. I have a feeling I'm missing out on a collection which can act much faster than the other two in certain situations. When is the ideal time to use these and how?

Answer (score 14):

`NSSet` is used when you frequently wish to test for *membership* of an object, but don't care about the ordering and don't need the collection to contain duplicate objects. An `NSSet` doesn't store its objects in any particular order; rather, the class is expressly designed to efficiently test whether an object *exists* in the collection.

The same goes for `NSCountedSet`, although `NSCountedSet` also keeps a *count* of duplicated objects.

So in a nutshell: use a set when you are concerned about testing for *membership*, rather than just keeping a collection of objects (some of which may be duplicated, as decided by an `isEqualTo` method of some sort).

Answer (score 11):

Following up on midpadi, Many uses of NSArray should be replaced with NSSet. NSSet is a collection of unique objects. NSArray is a collection of ordered objects. If your objects do not have an inherent order and are unique, you should use NSSet.

I very often keep an NSSet in the model layer, and let the UI components who require an order create their own NSArrays. For instance, consider the case of a "buddy list" made up of "buddies." The buddy list is itself unordered; it's just a collection. And the objects need to be unique. At the UI layer, however, you want an order, and you might even want to put the same buddy in multiple groups (Favorite and Offline for instance). But these are UI issues, and the model layer shouldn't need to worry about them.

```
NSSet *buddies = [buddyList allBuddies];
BOOL isBuddy = [buddyList containsObject:buddy];

NSArray *buddyList = [[buddyList allBuddies] sortedAraryUsingSelector:[self buddySortSelector]];
```

When a new buddy shows up, BuddyList will post a notification (`BuddyListDidAddBuddiesNotification`), that includes an NSSet of added buddies in its userInfo. So UI elements who are observing this can insert the buddies into their lists in whatever sort order is appropriate. This makes list animations very easy, which is much harder if you maintain all your sorted versions at the model layer.

When you have two NSSets, it's pretty easy to figure out the differences between them and construct a series of deletes and adds to turn one into the other (again, useful for animations). It's much more complicated to do this with NSArray.

So my recommendation is to default to NSSet. You should only use NSArray when you actually need ordering. This is unfortunately backwards of how most people do it.

Comment: Its confusing, because Apple doesn't always follow this pattern: for instance, [NSDictionary allValues] returns an NSArray, even though the documentation says the order of the values isn't defined. But I guess allValues is probably really really old.

Comment: Confusing matters there is now `NSOrderedSet`. Core data uses this for ordered to-many relationships

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, which talk mainly of Sets but not so much of Counted Sets, you might be wondering when is best to use a counted set. A counted set is useful for things like weighting or other statistical algorithms: at the end you can ultimately create an ordered array of its contents sorted using the stored count.

Another option would be in uniquing tables, or in a form of reference counter/garbage collector. Using a counted set would enable tests for inclusion (i.e. returning an existing identical object rather than creating a new one—similar to what CoreData does internally) whilst also performing a sort of reference counting on the values it includes, since the object would only be released by the set once its count reaches 0.